# MVVM Light Toolkit VerifyPropertyName

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light, mvvm-toolkit

In the Design View of a Silverlight page I am getting the following error: -

Property not found

Parameter name: batchGender

at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName)

etc....

In the ViewModel there was a property name called batchGender which I have changed to Gender. There are no other occurrences of batchGender anywhere. This is the result of a 'Find in Files' search in VS: -

*Find all "batchGender", Subfolders, Keep modified files open, Find Results 1, "Current Project", ""
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 90*

As you can see that string cannot be found anywhere, however the error will not go away. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the MVVM toolkit thinks this still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like one of your binaries is outdated, and maybe your project dependencies are incorrect.  Try cleaning the entire solution (and if applicable, any dependencies), and then rebuilding.

Comment: Closing down the project and reopening seemed to sort it out